# String Concatenation within a loop in Lua

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, lua, concatenation

I am trying to create some data by populating a Lua String. Instead of repeatedly creating the string, I want to make a loop. But when I do this in C#, Visual Studio gives me this..

NLua.Exceptions.LuaString.Exception:[string "chunk"]:4: syntax error near '='

```
    for i = 0,1,1 do
    ('forest'..i) = Group:Entity('forest'..' '..i,'Forest') 
    end
```

Comment: It's probably better to use an array instead; `local forests = {}; for i=0,1,1 do forests[i] = Group:Entity("forest "..i, "Forest") end`

Answer (score 1):

You are tryin to assign a value to a value. That's quite nonsensical, you can only assign to variables.

If `'forest'..i` results in a string whose value is the name of a global, you might be able to save that thing by indexing the globals-table: `_ENV['forest'..i]`.

A better idea is probably using a table though.

Comment: I am not trying to add a value to a value. What I want is forest1 = Group:Entity('forest 1','Forest'). There should be no space in the variable. I am able to concatenate inside but not for the variable declaration

Comment: Please re-read. I'm not saying you are trying to add anything at all.

Comment: This basically what he meant (if you didn't get it).
`for i = 0,1,1 do
 _ENV['forest'..i] = Group:Entity('forest'..' '..i,'Forest') 
end`